# Cassandra: table and secondary index update - is it atomic?

Tags: cassandra

Please clarify:

if table `A` does have a secondary index on column `COL1`, and a new row is inserted to `A`, are `A` and `A's index` updated transactionally? Is there a window where `A` and `A's index` hold inconsistent state?

Sources saying table and index **ARE NOT** updated transactionally:

- [Secondary index update issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334447/secondary-index-update-issue)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136640/why-does-cassandra-recommend-against-creating-an-index-on-high-cardinality-colum

Sources saying table and index **ARE** updated transactionally:

- https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/SecondaryIndexes

Answer (score 0):

Secondary indexes are consistent once an index is built. For performance reasons, writes are not atomic.  Instead, checks are applied lazily at read time to ensure consistency.

Sam Tunnicliffe, who helped implement this, explains how consistency is maintained in [Improving Secondary Index Write Performance in 1.2](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improving-secondary-index-write-performance-in-1-2) and the related [CASSANDRA-2897](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2897).